# Jquery dynatables loads correctly on page.ready but goes away on .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I'm missing something conceptually easy here, so I apologize ahead of time.

I have a table, and when the page loads or refreshes the content is displayed correctly; highlighting any rows with dates older than 24 hours.
(it runs the bottom function, highlighting a row.)

However, when I click one of my .change functions in the page, the highlighting goes away.

I feel like I have that function that highlights the row in the wrong spot, but I'm not sure how to update it. I tried pasting it into the .change method, but the highlighting still did not update.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var dynatable = $('#statusTable').dynatable({
      features: {
        paginate: true,
        recordCount: false,
        sorting: false
      }
    }).data('dynatable');

    $('#search-platform').change(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (value === "") {
        dynatable.queries.remove("platform");
      } else {
        dynatable.queries.add("platform", value);
      }
      dynatable.process();
    });

    $('#search-type').change(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (value === "") {
        dynatable.queries.remove("family");
      } else {
        dynatable.queries.add("family", value);
      }
      dynatable.process();
    });

    var TODAY = new Date();
    var ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; /* ms */
    //document.write(new Date(Date.parse('12/14/15 22:06:58')));

    $('#statusTable tr td').each(function() {
      if (TODAY >= (Date.parse($(this).text()) + ONE_DAY)) {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#CCCCCC');
      }
    });
  });
```